# C/C++ array variable in function header

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function, variables

We can pass an array as a variable in a C/C++ function header, as in

```
int func(int arr[]) { ... }
```

I'm wondering: Is it ever possible that something goes inside the `[]` in a variable that's passed into the function header, or is it always empty?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference until you use a reference, pointer to array, or multidimensional array.

Comment: It's different for C and C++.  C has VLAs.  C++ has templates.

Comment: *"We can pass an array as a variable in a C/C++ function header, as in*" - Nope. In your example the function gets a pointer to the first element, not an array.  Try it yourself; `sizeof arr == sizeof int*`, always.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any (non-reference) type `T`, the function signatures  `R foo(T t[])` and `R foo(T t[123])` (or any other number) are identical to `R foo(T * t)`, and arrays are passed by passing the address of the first element.

Note that `T` may itself be an array type, such as `T = U[10]`.

Comment: +1 for the abstraction. I've never heard it like that, but it's good.

Answer (score 3):

for a one-dimensional array, it will always be empty, the brackets are another way of writing:

```
int fun(int * arr)
{

}
```

As for a two-dimensional array, you need to specify how many elements each element itself holds

```
int fun(int arr[][3])
{

}
```

Comment: It can have a number between the brackets, even if it is one dimensional, the compiler just ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

int func(int arr[]) { ... }
 is an invalid decleration of an array passed to a function.

An array name is a pointer variable. so it is enough that we just pass the array name (which itself is a pointer )

int func(int *arr) { ... } 
will pass the starting address of the array to the function so that it can use the array.

if the original array needs to be kept intact, a copy of the array can be created & used within the function.

Answer (score 0):

The **name** of an array decays into a **pointer** to its first element in most contexts. So when you write

```
void f(int arr[]);
void g(int arr[42]);
```

the name `arr` decays into a pointer to int. The two declarations are equivalent to these:

```
void f(int *arr);
void g(int *arr);
```

Two places where the name does not decay are in the definition of an array and as an argument to `sizeof`. So this declaration at global scope does not define a pointer to int:

```
int arr[];
```

I mention this particular one because it's an easy mistake to make and one that's hard to track down. This defines an array, not a pointer, even though the number of elements is not specified. It is an error (but one that doesn't have to be diagnosed) to refer to `arr` from another source file as `int *arr;`.